# What's currently the fastest way to get data in memory of one computer into memory of other computer?

Tags: distributed-computing

What's currently the fastest way of making data in memory of one server available in the memory of another server?

Of course I I can use regular networking - but I could imagine there being faster links available for mainstream server hardware, like pci-e or SAS based direct communication or maybe even DMA in some way?
I'm not just interested at max throughput but also minimal latency

Answer (score 1):

Im sure there are other options, but the one I hear being used the most is [InfiniBand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InfiniBand).

> InfiniBand (IB) is a computer networking communications standard used in high-performance computing that features very high throughput and very low latency. It is used for data interconnect both among and within computers. InfiniBand is also used as either a direct or switched interconnect between servers and storage systems, as well as an interconnect between storage systems. It is designed to be scalable and uses a switched fabric network topology.

Answer (score 0):

@keltari is going to be pretty close to the right answer for the networking fabric with Infiniband (IB) but was pretty broad. The most realistic Infiniband standard right now that's the fastest is [HDR](https://www.mellanox.com/products/infiniband-switches/QM8700). I believe there are technically faster IB standards, but in practice, HDR is the fastest. Also the most expensive. 200GB/s.

Don't count out Ethernet though. The newer standards of Ethernet are also very fast. I've personally never seen Ethernet that's capable over 40GB/s, but it exists - [TbE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terabit_Ethernet) (Terabit Ethernet, 400-800GB/s but I'm not sure if that's what it actually gets right now or just the theoretical standard for it like the next level of IB is supposed to get).

There was a 3rd "standard" in high speed networking for a short while called OPA (Omni-Path Architecture). This his 100GB/s but was cancelled by Intel before it got to the second standard which was supposed to be 200 GB/s in [2019](https://www.crn.com/news/components-peripherals/intel-kills-2nd-gen-omni-path-interconnect-for-hpc-ai-workloads).

You can also really speed up movement from ram to ram by using protocols such as RDMA (remote direct memory access).

> In computing, remote direct memory access (RDMA) is a direct memory access from the memory of one computer into that of another without involving either one's operating system. This permits high-throughput, low-latency networking, which is especially useful in massively parallel computer [clusters.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_direct_memory_access)